# IBM Integration Desinger 8.x has a plugin for SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarlint

I am trying to configure SonarQube Plugin with IBM IID 8 as its based on Eclipse I thought i will  be able to configure it easily with SonarQube, but its not working. I try to find out on IBM website but not have any luck.

Can somebody tell me if there is anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

IID 8.5.5 runs on Eclipse Helios 3.6.3 .. you need to find a plugin version which is compatible with this Eclipse version.

You can also install Eclipse Market Place into IBM Integration Designer

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/mpc/releases/1.0.1/mpc-1.0.1.zip